# D3 How to zoom in on SVG text that stays within an SVG Rectangle?

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

I am trying to zoom in on a rectangle that has text appended inside. I am using `getBBox()` to determine the size of the text and then drawing a rectangle based on the size of that text. From there I tried adding zoom/pan functionality.

Unfortunately when you zoom in, the text and rectangle do not scale the same way. When you zoom in, the text scales way too much and it does not stay within the rectangle. Actually it seems the rectangle only will encapsulate the text at the default zoom level.

http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/1/

I'm not sure if I should be scaling the rectangle or the text inside to the other. I'm trying to play around with the redraw function to see if I can transform the size with the current width of the text so I will update my jsfiddle if I get any progress. If anyone can give me some advice on this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Works fine in IE (after correcting it to remove the extra `<svg>` element) [jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/2](http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/2/).  I can't get it to display anything in FireFox.

Comment: Hmmm I didn't try it in firefox... I'm not sure why it isn't working there but I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: You need to style the <html> and <body> with width: 100% and height: 100% and also set the height and width attributes on the outer <svg> element to 100%

Comment: @RobertLongson I just tried this and it didn't seem to work. Can you possibly fork my jsFiddle and show me what you did? Do you have to add those attributes through d3 or just pure CSS?

Comment: Ask another question, this one isn't really about that issue.

Comment: Once you get it working, FireFox doesn't have the zoom bug: [jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/4](http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/4/)

Comment: I think I got it to work in Chrome! I updated my JSFiddle! Apparently I Need to specify `.attr('font-size')`? At least for now it seems to be working. However, I still am having trouble with it working in IE9... @gilly3 you said it worked? I can see it but it does not zoom/pan for me.

Comment: @aug - Great! But, revert the latest edit to your question and post the solution as an answer. Yes, it works for me in IE10 and IE9-mode. I'm zooming with my scroll wheel and panning with click and drag. Is there another way to zoom or pan?

Comment: @gilly3 For some reason after going into developer tools in IE9, it works... Kinda quirky @_@... But thank you so much for all your help! ^_^ if you want you can submit an answer regarding IE and Firefox and I'll give you an upvote? I included your answer in mine though :] once again really appreciate the help!

Comment: You are calling `console.log()` but, `window.console` is `undefined` until you open the dev tools in IE.  Use `window.console && console.log('whatever');`.  http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cWWW/6/

Changes that needed to be made for this to work:

**IE:**

Apparently I needed to remove the extra `<svg>` element I had at the top when appending.

**Firefox:**

Apparently you need to set the `width` and `height` of the SVG as shown here:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("height","100%").attr("width","100%")
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
              .append("g");
```

Thank you so much to **gilly3** for telling me this.

**Chrome:**

Apparently you need to make sure you specify the `font-size` attribute:

```
var text = svg.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 480)
    .attr("y", 250)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", nodeFontSize + "px") //<-- added
    .text("This is the text I want to make zoomable");
```

Hope this helps everyone!